# Instance and class methods in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Recently I saw a quite odd code in Ruby on Rails http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

```
   class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default :from => "ryan@railscasts.com"

      def registration_confirmation(user)
        @user = user
        attachments["rails.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png")
        mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered")
      end
    end

    #controller
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
```

How is it possible? `registration_confirmation` is not a class method ( or kind of like a static one in C#), it's an **instance** method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky.

Because it derives from AbstractController, the methods defined are added as public instance methods. (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

You never instantiate your mailer class. Rather, you just call the method you defined on the class itself.

If you examine [AbstractController::Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1eb6189404f53ae59e4cb47ef9d5ad3a9bec3064/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb), you can see where the class is abstracted and the action methods are turned into public instance methods.